# Any equivalent function of ARM's ldrb in x86 gas syntax?

Tags: assembly, x86, gnu-assembler

I'm looking to load a string byte by byte to check for a null value that signifies the termination of that string in x86. I had prior done this in ARM using ldrb as such:

```
loop:
    ldrb    r1, [r0], #1 //Load next byte of string into r0
    cmp     r1, #0 //Check this byte against 0
    beq     end //If the byte is equal stop and print
    //... Other operations omitted  
    b       loop//Branch back to top
```

In this example r0 holds the string and ldrb is used to load the next 1 byte into r1 per loop cycle. I'd be looking to do roughly the same thing in x86

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surely you have an instruction set reference. There is really no way around knowing the basic data movement and comparison instructions. You shouldn't rely on being spoon-fed.

That said, the x86 counterpart to `ldrb` is called `movzbl` (**mov**e **z**ero extended **b**yte to **l**ong, called `movzx` in intel syntax). Here is a sample implementation using `eax` for `r0`  and `edx` for `r1`:

```
loop:
    movzbl 1(%eax), %edx
    cmpl $0, %edx
    je end
    // ... other operations omitted
    jmp loop
```

Also note that x86 is CISC and supports operating on memory directly, meaning you can compare a value in memory to `0` without loading into a register. You can use that if you don't need the value of the character.

Furthermore, certain parts of x86 registers can be used directly, in this case you could write `movb 1(%eax), %dl` to use the low 8 bits of `%edx`. The top 24 bits then stay unchanged, so you should only use byte-sized comparison too.

Speaking of the comparison, common idioms for zero testing include using `and`, `or` or `test` instructions with both operands being the register in question, such as `test %edx, %edx`. This is done because these produce shorter machine code.

Comment: Thanks, everything seems to be in order now. I really appreciate it! I do have an instruction set reference but, it's a bit convoluted, I spent the past day or so trying to figure it out.